# Adding HTML class to Ajax.RouteForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an Ajax.Routeform whose systax is given as:`

```
@using (Ajax.BeginRouteForm("Contact", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod =  "POST", OnSuccess = "emailSuccess", OnFailure = "emailFailure" })) 
{
}
```

I need to add a html class "form-horizontal" to it. How can I achieve this?
The method overload containg html attributes is

```
Ajax.Routeform( string routeName, object routeValues,  AjaxOptions ajaxOptions, object htmlAttributes )
```

`

Comment: `@using (Ajax.BeginRouteForm("Contact", null, new AjaxOptions { ... }, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))`

Comment: Thanks :) found the solution as well

Comment: should i answer it myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method overload for htmlAttributes is

```
Ajax.Routeform( string routeName, object routeValues,  AjaxOptions ajaxOptions, object htmlAttributes )
```

Since routeValues is not required I can pass null in it and the syntax is quite stright forward

```
@using (Ajax.BeginRouteForm("Contact", null, new AjaxOptions { ... }, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
```

Comment: Apparently adding "form-horizontal" to form was a bad idea, broke the layout. I had to a div wrapper inside form and give it "form-horizontal" class.